# Plot when parameters are in a region

Tags: plotting, regions

Following [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-plot-a-function-whose-constant-parameters-have-associated-uncertainties-i) (which is *nearly* what I need):

I want to plot the function `a + bx`, but the parameters `a` and `b` have an "uncertainty" in such a way that they can only be in a particular region, say:

[image: 2D region for parameters a and b]

If parameters have independent uncertainties, then the answer to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-plot-a-function-whose-constant-parameters-have-associated-uncertainties-i) is ok:

```
With[{a = Interval[1.01 + .18 {-1, 1}], b = Interval[.92 + .11 {-1, 1}]}, 
  Plot[{Min[a + b*x], 1.01 + .92 x, Max[a + b*x]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {3}}, 
    FillingStyle -> Darker, 
    PlotStyle -> {None, Red, None}]]
```

With a succesful output:

[image]

However, I need to modify the `With` so that a and b are not in independent intervals, but inside the region specified by `Reg` (see image). This is, for every x I want to plot the maximum and the minimum of a complicated function whose parameters should be in a particular region.

I've tried something similar to `{a, b} = Reg` or `{a, b} ∈ Reg` but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Need more information to help - try to post a minimal working example that shows what you want to do. But take a look at [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)

Comment: Please, post code and try to format your question as to present a clear, self-contained entity.

Comment: Let me edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: Without knowing the "complicated function" you want to minimize, I think the approach used by m_goldberg is the right way to go:  `MinValue[{< my function of x, a, and b >, 
  1/4 < a^2 + b^2 && a^2 + b^2 < 1}, {a, b}]` and `MaxValue[{< my function of x, a, and b >, 
  1/4 < a^2 + b^2 && a^2 + b^2 < 1}, {a, b}]`

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be asking for a mathematical impossibility. The linear function `1.01 + .92 x` does not stay in the parameter space you wish to impose on it.

The parameter space looks like this.

```
paramSpace = 
  With[{r = ImplicitRegion[a^2 + b^2 < 1, {{a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}}]},
    Plot[
      {Evaluate @ MinValue[a + b*x, {a, b} ∈ r], 
       Evaluate @ MaxValue[a + b*x, {a, b} ∈ r]}, 
      {x, -5, 5},
      Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
      FillingStyle -> Darker]]
```

[image: params]

However, `1.01 + .92 x` does not stay within it.

```
Show[
  paramSpace,
  Plot[1.01 + .92 x, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: plot]

Note: the lower bound of 1/4 does not have any effect on the problem and so I have omitted it.

Comment: Beat me to it - also, is good to point out that `MinValue[{a x + b, 1/4 < a^2 + b^2 && a^2 + b^2 < 1}, {a, b}]` gives an analytic solution, as does `MaxValue`.  But I think the line `1.01 + .92 x` is unrelated here.  The OP says they want to minimize "a complicated function" so I don't know if it's linear at all - but it's hard to help without knowing what is asked.

Comment: @JasonB. Ah. I should have looked at output of `MinValue`, and not just thrown it into the plot. It speeds up the plot quite a bit to use the analytic solution. I have made an edit. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain intervals for `a` and `b` with the help of `Reduce`.

```
Reduce[a^2 + b^2 < 1 && a^2 + b^2 > (1/2)^2, b]
```

I don't know how to transform the reduced solutions elegantly into `Interval` expressions. But plugging in the first interval pair by hand:

```
Module[{a, b, min, max},
 a = Interval[{-1, -(1/2)}];
 b = Interval[{-Sqrt[1 - a^2], Sqrt[1 - a^2]}];
 min[e_] := MapAt[Min, e, Position[e, Interval[_]]];
 max[e_] := MapAt[Max, e, Position[e, Interval[_]]];
 Plot[{min[a + b x], max[a + b x]}, {x, -5, 5},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
  ImageSize -> Small]]
```

[image]